Conversion of boronic acid (esters) to azides
I was looking at the following paper: https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC2879648/
It claims that the conversion of boronic esters and pinacolates (1 mmol scale) to organic azides is directly possible via the Chan-Lam coupling with an excess of sodium azide in a methanol "solution" (5 ml) and copper acetate catalysis (10 mol%). The solution has to be stirred at 55 °C for 3 hours approx.
My question is: I wanted to use this procedure for my product, which is bulky with a triazole unit, and is basically like the Deferasirox framework, with a boron pinacolate functionality. The problem is that my compound is quite poorly soluble in methanol, and I don't know if the conversion works properly. Purification is quite difficult, as yields are low at the moment.

Would be using more solvent feasible here? I don't know if it is possible that it will affect the outcome of the reaction, or if using another solvent will influence it as well.

Could try MeCN or MeCN/DMSO as done in Org. Lett., 2013, 15, 3058-3061   It may also be advantageous to switch to Lithium Azide as it is more soluble in organic solvents
